# Implementing Custom Generic Class with Inheritance

Tags: c#, class, generics, inheritance

I want implementing a generic class that inheritance from another generic class, like :

```
Public Class QlistedLink<T> : Linkedlist<T>
```

My problem is in IEnumrable Functions! when i call any of this like,

```
QlistedLink<int> Q = new QlistedLink<int>();
int temp = Q.First();
```

throw an error on First() function :

"Sequence contains no elements"

what is solving way ?

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem. You haven't given us *nearly* enough information at the moment.

Comment: -1 It is not the bad English.

Answer (score 3):

Of course you get an exception here; what `int` are you *expecting* to get out of an empty list?

Either add something to the list before calling `First` on it, or call `FirstOrDefault` which will give you `0` if the list is empty, or check the list is not empty before calling `First`.

Comment: :|  I surly add some data to my class and then call this function !